# Getting 400 bad request with WCF service called through WebRequest using C#

Tags: wcf, soap, httpwebrequest, webrequest

After some changes in code and going through loads of links I was able to write the following code to call WCF service method with SOAP message. Now I get 400 Bad Request error, whatever I change (tried HttpWebRequest) I still get this error. Not sure what am I missing:

```
private string WebServiceCall()
{
    WebRequest req = WebRequest.Create("http://klo239fu.mass.win.tf.com/WCFTestService/Service.svc");
    req.ContentType = "application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8";
    req.Method = "POST";
    req.Headers.Add("SOAPAction", "http://tempuri.org/GetSimpleType");
    using(Stream reqStream = req.GetRequestStream())
    {
        var bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(txtFormattedSoap.Text);
        reqStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
        reqStream.Close();
    }
    var wr = (WebRespose)req.GetResponse();
    var srd = new StreamReader(wr.GetResponseStream());
    txtResponse.Text = srd.ReadToEnd();
}
```

**SOAP Request (from SOAP client)**

```
POST /WCFTestService/Service.svc HTTP/1.1
Host: klo239fu.mass.win.tf.com
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length
SOAPAction: "wsf-test-service/IService/GetSimpleType"

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
 <soap:Body>
 <GetSimpleType xmlns="wsf-test-service">
  <myvalue>int</myvalue>
 </GetSimpleType>
 </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Here is the SOAP request that is patterened to above soap enveope that I pass in my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soap:Body><GetSimpleType xmlns="wcf-test-service"><myvalue>1234</myvalue></GetSimpleType></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>
```

Earlier I had content type test/xml but code throwed "(415) Cannot process the message because the content type 'text/xml' was not the expected type.". So I changed the content type="application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8" but it fails with (400) Bad request.

Answer (score 2):

I'm saw antoher post you did and I think that you and I are currently working on the same thing. Invoking web services dynamically. Loading WSDLs, using dynamic proxies and reflection and all that fun stuff.

I have a suggestion for this error that you see.
I have had a similar issue with one of the web services I used. Even if the Action in the header is supposted to be optional, it did manage to get my call to fail when I passed in the address (uri) as you have. When I passed in the name of the operation instead it worked. So try and change this:

```
req.Headers.Add("SOAPAction", "http://tempuri.org/GetSimpleType");
```

To the name of the method in the WSDL instead. That is the name of the System.ServiceModel.Description.OperationDescription. It is probably "GetSimpleType".

```
req.Headers.Add("SOAPAction", "GetSimpleType");
```

Comment: Hi Karin
Glad to see someone working on similar thing otherwise I didn't find any resource for WCF/Soap Request. Changing the code as you suggested didn't make it work either :( May be I am still missing something here. At first I thought that it may be 'coz of the way wsdl is being generated for WCF (multiple xsd reference) but then I generated single wsdl and it failed again. Can you share the piece of your code?